# Receber 2 parametros ao informar um parametro chave

Tags: java, lista

Tenho um código que é relacionado a 2 valores, por exemplo:

1253 (código), São Paulo (primeiro valor, no caso o estado), e Osasco (segundo valor, no caso, a cidade).

Gostaria de saber se há alguma maneira em lista, ou em algum tipo de classe especifica aonde eu apenas informe o código que preciso e receba os 2 valores (strings) relacionados a ele.

Eu pensei em algumas formas que isso possa funcionar, mas tenho receio que sejam mais gambiarras, por isso gostaria de opiniões diversas.

Comment: Alguma resposta ajudou a resolver o problema e pode sanar dúvidas similares de outros usuários? Caso positivo não esqueça de marcar a resposta como aceita. Pra fazer isso é só clicar no ✓ do lado esquerdo da mesma (abaixo do indicador de up e down votes).

Answer (score 3):

Uma das possíveis soluções é trabalhar com um [**HashMap**](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/HashMap.html), que receba como key o código,  e outro `HashMap` como valor, onde você salvará o par estado-cidade.

```
public class MapTest {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
    //map principal
    Map<Integer, HashMap<String, String>> codeStateList = new HashMap<>();  
    //cria um map para cruzar estado cidade
    HashMap<String, String> stateCity = new HashMap<>();
    //adiciona o par estado cidade
    stateCity.put("Sao paulo", "Osasco");
    //salva no map principal o code cruzando com map com par estado-cidade
    codeStateList.put(1253, stateCity);
    //para exibir ou pegar o par
    System.out.println(codeStateList.get(1253));
    }
}
```

A saida será:

> {Sao paulo=Osasco}

Pode ser visto em funcionamento no [**IDEONE**](https://ideone.com/ygtf5N)

---

Você também pode crar uma classe a parte, que seja responsavel por manipular esse `HashMap`. Fiz um exemplo o mais basico possível de como poderia ser essa classe, apenas para ilustrar como seria a construção:

```
class StateCityMap {

    private final Map<Integer, HashMap<String, String>> codeStateList;

    public StateCityMap() {
        codeStateList = new HashMap<>();
    }

    public void putStateCity(int code, String state, String city) {
        HashMap<String, String> stateCity = new HashMap<>();
        stateCity.put(state, city);
        codeStateList.put(code, stateCity);
    }

    public String getStateCity(int key) {
        return this.containsKey(key) ? codeStateList.get(key).toString() : null;
    }

    public void removeStateCity(int key) {
        for (Iterator<Map.Entry<Integer, HashMap<String, String>>> iterator = codeStateList.entrySet().iterator(); iterator.hasNext();) {
            Map.Entry<Integer, HashMap<String, String>> entry = iterator.next();
            if (entry.getKey().equals(key)) {
                iterator.remove();
            }
        }
    }

    public boolean containsKey(int key) {
        return codeStateList.containsKey(key);
    }

    public String showAllItens() {
        String allItens = "";
        for (Map.Entry<Integer, HashMap<String, String>> entry : codeStateList.entrySet()) {
            allItens += entry.getKey() + " : " + entry.getValue() + "\n";
        }
        return allItens;
    }
}
```

Seu uso:

```
public class StateCityClassTest {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        StateCityMap map = new StateCityMap();

        map.putStateCity(1253, "São Paulo", "Osasco");
        map.putStateCity(1254, "São Paulo", "Santos");
        map.putStateCity(1255, "Rio de Janeiro", "Cabo Frio");

        System.out.println(map.getStateCity(1253));

        System.out.println(map.showAllItens());

    }
}
```

Veja funcionando no [**IDEONE**](https://ideone.com/mr4w3G).

Answer (score 1):

Uma maneira é você utilizar a classe [`Multimap`](https://google.github.io/guava/releases/19.0/api/docs/com/google/common/collect/Multimap.html) da biblioteca [`Guava`](https://github.com/google/guava) do Google.

O uso seria o seguinte:

```
ListMultimap<Integer, String> cidades = ArrayListMultimap.create();

cidades.put(1253, "São Paulo");
cidades.put(1253, "Osasco");

System.out.println(cidades.get(1253));
```

Caso você esteja usando `Maven` você pode adicionar a dependência do projeto assim:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>com.google.guava</groupId>
  <artifactId>guava</artifactId>
  <version>20.0</version>
</dependency>
```

Ou baixar o .jar [aqui](http://search.maven.org/remotecontent?filepath=com/google/guava/guava/20.0/guava-20.0.jar).

Você pode obter [aqui](https://github.com/google/guava/wiki/Release20) maiores explicações sobre o último release (20);

Comment: Quem negativou pode falar o motivo? Se tiver algo errado eu posso corrigir na resposta

Comment: Não fui eu quem negavitou. Pra falar a verdade, montei minha resposta baseado no que li no SOEn, e até vi essa solução, mas não adicionei na resposta, já estava complexa demais, preferi focar apena no HashMap.

Comment: Qual a diferença desse `ListMultimap` para um `HashMap`? No contexto da pergunta.

Comment: @renan a diferença é que essa estrutura foi desenhada justamente para o que ele quer, que é uma chave com vários itens dentro. Ela é um HashMap de listas, sem precisar de uma nova implementação

Comment: @diegofm eu imaginei que não tinha sido você mesmo, tranquilo, só queria saber qual foi o motivo pra melhorar a resposta caso ela tenha algo errado mesmo, já que no meu caso quando eu precisei de algo assim achei que serviu como uma luva